# Back-propagation in Neural Nets with >2 hidden layers

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent

We have the following update formulas:

Output layer (indexed by $k \in \{1, \dots, \text{number of classes} \}$).

$o_k$ - value of output neuron $k$

$d_k$ - desired value of output neuron $k$

$\eta$ - learning rate

$x_j$ - value of neuron on the last hidden layer

$$\delta_k = o_k(1 - o_k)(d_k - o_k)$$
$$\omega_{jk} = \omega_{jk} + \Delta\omega_{jk}, \text{where } \Delta\omega_{jk} = \eta\delta_kx_j$$

Last hidden layer (HL) (indexed by $j \in \{1, \dots, \text{number of hidden neurons in the last HL} \}$):
$$\delta_j = x_j(1 - x_j)\sum_k \omega_{jk}\delta_k$$
$$\omega_{ij} = \omega_{ij} + \Delta\omega_{ij}, \text{where } \Delta\omega_{ij} = \eta\delta_j x_i$$

**Does this update formulas hold generally for any number of hidden layers? I.e.:**

$l$-th hidden layer ($l \in [0..L]$, where 0 - input layer, $L$ - output layer) (indexed by $p \in \{1, \dots, \text{number of hidden neurons in layer } l\},$

$j \in \{\text{ 1,..,number of hidden neurons in layer } l+1\}$

$$\delta_p = x_p(1 - x_p)\sum_j \omega_{pj}\delta_j$$
$$\omega_{pj} = \omega_{pj} + \Delta\omega_{pj}, \text{where } \Delta\omega_{pj} = \eta\delta_j x_p$$

If it is true, it's possible to recursively compute all $\delta$s for all neurons (except the input ones) starting with output and going deeper to the hidden nodes and then simply modify the each weight based on found $\delta$ and $x$. Correct?

Comment: Using more hidden layers will increase complexity in the network architecture which in turns increase the training time

Comment: @Oleg, did you try your said way ? Actually now I was also searching for same. Please provide your views.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a simple computation of the partial derivative and observation, that the derivative on the layer $i$ (from top) can be fully computed using partial derivative for weights in layer $i-1$. This applies to any number of layers, but this leads to so called "vanishing gradient phenomenon" which is a reason for not using multiple hidden layers in general (at least with **basic architecture** and **basic training**). To overcome this issue, deep learning has been proposed in recent years (like for example Deep Convolutional Networks, Deep Belief Networks, Deep Autoencoders, Deep Boltzmann Machines etc.)